# Why can associated constants not depend on type parameters?

Tags: rust

Is this just a current limitation or is there a technical reason? As generic functions get compiled to specialized code, I don’t see what should prevent it from working. It also works fine in the `main` function.

Example ([playground](http://is.gd/AMBcVY)):

```
#![feature(associated_consts)]
trait HasNumber<T> {
    const Number: usize;
}

enum One {}
enum Two {}

enum Foo {}

impl<T> HasNumber<One> for T {
    const Number: usize = 1;
}

impl<T> HasNumber<Two> for T {
    const Number: usize = 2;
}

fn use_number<T, H: HasNumber<T>>() {
    let a: [u8; H::Number] = unsafe { ::std::mem::uninitialized() };
}

fn main() {
    let a: [u8; <Foo as HasNumber<One>>::Number] = unsafe { ::std::mem::uninitialized() };
    println!("{}", <Foo as HasNumber<One>>::Number); 
    println!("{}", <Foo as HasNumber<Two>>::Number);    
}
```

Comment: Well the first thing that strikes me, is that associated consts define the const in the for part i.e `HasNumber for Two` rather than `HasNumber<Two> for T`. However I already encountered some ICEs here, so I think it's just this feature being very new.

Comment: Thanks, that PR comment answers my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: It's not implemented yet, since it's hard to get right. There's even an open RFC named "[Constants that depend on type parameters in generic code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1062)" for it.

Long answer:

This used to be a [compiler-bug that caused the compiler to crash](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25046). It was "fixed" by @quantheory in [PR 25091](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/25091) by making this an error instead of a crash. @quantheory commented that

> I haven't been able to deal with the array size or recursion issues yet for associated consts, though my hope was that the change I made for range match patterns might help with array sizes, too.

@quantheory also notes that this will stay an error until something along the lines of [RFC 1062](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1062) is merged. Comments on the RFC are always appreciated, as they might hilight forgotten use-cases.

Comment: This is out of date. Following the chain of closed issues starting at RFC 1062, tracking for this particular issue seems to have been lost.